# need simple jQuery slideshow with corresponding links for each image

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slider

I have a client who has a simple slider that shows images of friends. There is a list of hyperlinks underneath that corresponds to each slider image. My client wants each link to highlight to green (like a:hover) as each slider image is shown. It would also be nice for the slider image to link to her friend's pages as well.

Here is the current [site](http://www.toneblu.com/ashleighjuarez/friends.html).

Are there any super simple jQuery plugins that can do this? I've researched the [Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and also the Gallerific plugin, but I am having troubles making them do what I want. The slider needs to start automatically with no other buttons.

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: I tried implementing the Gallerific plugin. But its hyperlinks point to the next or previous images, not to outside links as I want. I have not had success modifying it to my needs.

The Cycle plugin is simple and starts automatically, but does not provide text links for each image in slideshow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Comment: thank you, but I am not looking for a carousel. I need a simple automatic slideshow similar to the Cycle plugin, but with hyperlinks that highlight with each image.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding exactly what you need, but that carousel has an autoscroll feature and functions (beforeStart and afterEnd) that can be used to highlight whichever link you want.

Comment: I found a solution that works with this tutorial which utilizes the Cycle plugin:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript/

Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works with this tutorial which utilizes the Cycle plugin:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript/

Thanks for the input though.